# What are the stages of freelance software development project?

Tags: untagged

I'm new in freelancing, I'm software developer and I want to know the stages of freelance software development project?

In freelancing you're the CEO and the whole company, and as my full day career I'm only a developer not a salesman nor PM, so please I need to know what to do from the time customer call me to deliver the software and get the sign-off.

Comment: Are you asking for the full process, start to finish?

Comment: yes please, if it's very long you can give me points or a book to read.

Comment: Hey Emad, while this type of question is a bit too broad for our Q&A format, we definitely want you to come back and see us once you gain a bit more experience and have some more targeted questions. Check out [Freelance Switch - Getting Started as a Freelancer](http://freelanceswitch.com/blog/explore/getting-started-as-a-freelancer/), which should cover everything you'd need to know to get started. Hope this helps and good luck! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the fact you're coding off-site, the software delivering stages are not different from regular process. The only difference you may notice is yourself doing multiple roles.

Most likely you will be:

- coder
- project management
- QA
- lead developer writing specs
- designer when needed to chop out images from PSD or AI files

In other terms, the process is basically the same. Here are my stages:

- short discussion up to 2 hours and delivering of estimation (*doc: simpler SOW and Quote, 2 docs. Sometimes this stage include myself signing NDA*)
- negotiation on terms of payment and deadline. I prefer weekly payments (*docs: full SOW and Terms of Service, 2 docs*)
- coding and delivering app per set milestones (*Invoice every Friday. If new clients, do not start next week before last Invoice has been processed. With old client I keep working but also take care that I don't start 3rd week before 1st one being processed*)
- QA of app between starting next milestone
- delivery of final product
- after client finalizes all payments, sending of sources and other material I created in the process

Does this help?

Comment: What about the official documents? you're stages are perfect but can you add document like Terms Of Agreement, SOW, Quote, and Invoice in which stage?

Comment: Will edit the reply.